Why is Windows 10 on a second monitor taskbar not showing minimized icons?
I have a problem with the taskbar on Windows 10 22H2 (19045.4717). I briefly switched to not minimized icons on both taskbars but going back to show only icons the second monitor didn't change back to the old style.
imgur.com/a/HsUXDAD
I've tried restarting the PC, shutting down explorer.exe and restarting it and unplugging the monitor and replugging it again.

What cumulative update do you have installed. I been I remember a known issue related to the taskbar and minimized icons but it only effects a specific cumulative update. You can still provide images you can’t just inline them. Please prob those screenshots

https://imgur.com/a/HsUXDAD

I've so far installed all recommended cumulative updates. The latest one is KB5040525

You need to edit your question an include the screenshot. It won’t be an inline screenshot but it will be a URL to the screenshot.
